# NBodySimulation in ParallelTable

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization, physics

When I use the `NBodySimulation` in a `ParallelTable` I do not get multiple processors effectively activating. If I want to sweep over a few parameters (so doing a few thousand simulations) it would be great to speed this up.

Comment: Please show code. I tried to apply `ParallelTable` on the first example in the documentation, the one about springs, and it did parallelize the simulations.